# How to create a URL that modifies a particular cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mymaps

I have a google sheet where I have information about places. I used that sheet to populate a map on Google My Maps. I want to insert (create) a URL for every point of the map so when I clic on it the information in the sheet gets updated (for example chaging one cell value).

**¿Is it possible to create a URL that modifies a particula cell on a google shett when it´s visited? ¿How?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to pass information from a hyperlink to a Google Sheet is by using Google Forms as an intermediary - here's a [blog post](https://bionicteaching.com/silent-submission-of-google-forms/) I found that outlines how to set up a URL that prefills Google Form with certain answers and automatically submits it when clicked (by adding `&submit=Submit` to the URL). The Google Form answers are then available in a Google Sheet.

This isn't exactly a `google-apps-script` solution, but from here you could pass that information back to your original Google Sheet with an Apps Script function or with [ImportRange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) depending on the complexity of your needs.